# Find Source of Test Coverage

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, cobertura

I am currently dealing with a legacy Java Maven project that I need to alter. I have ran a test coverage report with cobertura and can see that the logic I have to change is currently covered by a test. Given that the code base is tens of thousands of classes in size, that the complexity of many of the classes and tests is very large, and that there they are not testing their code unit by unit opting for sort of semi-integration tests...I will have no luck manually tracking down which tests are providing this coverage.

What I'd ideally have is some way to find out that line `x` of source class `y` is covered by method `t` of test class `r`.

**Is there a way with cobertura or some other tool (hopefully a Maven plugin) that I can view the tests which actually cover each LoC?**

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint in your method, execute your test in debug mode, and then look at the call stack when the VM suspends.